# How much time does it take to transfer BTC into btc-e hosted wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallet, btce

If i'm buying BTC in person from someone and he sends it to my btc-e hosted wallet, how much time does it usually take to appear in the account balance? Is it like any regular transfer or are they doing some extra confirmations? Thanks!

Comment: 6 confirmations which usually takes anywhere from 20min to an hour.

Answer (score 1):

BTC-e waits for **three confirmations**, and then takes a minute or two more.

In my experience, it took 12 minutes. YMMV.

This is documented on the BTC-e website. Login, then click on 'finances', then click on the 'deposit' button on the BTC row.

The minimum incoming transfer is 0.0001BTC.  I don't know what happens if you transfer a smaller amount.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of factors there. It could depend on network volume, things like the way the online wallet is built, and what hardware is being used. Then, depending on the service, they could have additional rules for security, like requiring 10 or more confirmations. It's been my experience that high expectations for speed are bad with these services. What you want to do is plan to wait around an hour before everything confirms, and all of the internal policies are met.

Comment: Does it depend on bitcoin amount as well?